# Props in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am making a quiz app using react native. One file with all the code, then I call this class with all the code on another page.

I put this.props.score in the file with all code and in another file I call it using score={this.state.score}, but it shows nothing.

Why? Help me, please
Code:

// Function.js

```
render() {
  var questionDatum = this.props.questionDatum;
  var questLength = this.props.questLength
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.main}>
        {questLength > this.props.progress ? (
          <View>
            <View style={styles.viewQuesProg}>
              <Score score={this.props.score} />
            </View>
            <Questions questionDatum={questionDatum} />
          </View>
        ) : (
          <View>
            <Text>Your score: {this.props.score} </Text>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
}};

// Main.js 

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    questionData: [{
      prompt: "Q 1",
      answers: ['a', "b", "c", "d"], correct: 2
    },
    { prompt: "Q 2", answers: ["a", "b", "c", "d"], correct: 0 }],
    progress: 0,
    score: 0
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <Function
      questionDatum={this.state.questionData[this.state.progress]}
      questLength={this.state.questionData.length}
      progress={this.state.progress}
      score={this.state.score}
    />
  )
}
}

// ...
```

Score component:

```html
class Score extends React.Component {

    render() {
      return (
        <Text style={styles.progressText}>Score: {this.props.score}</Text>
      )
    }
  };
```

Comment: Can you also post code in Score component. Seems like there is some issue in that component.

Comment: @Kaushik I have posted, look up